# Remove marker on click in swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, marker

i tried to add marker on click and i did it !
but i want to have just 2 marker in google maps.
what should i do ?! 
here is my code in swift

```
    mapView.delegate = self

    }

func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
    marker.title = ""
    marker.snippet = ""
    marker.map = mapView   
}
```

i want to have a marker for home and a marker for destination

Comment: So you want to remove the previously added markers? Or do you simply want to stop adding markers after the first two taps?

Comment: second one ! Stop adding markers after the first two taps

Comment: then simply add a counter variable to your class, increase it on every tap and check on every tap wether or not is greater or equal to 2 in which case you do not add further markers

Comment: luk2302 - is right .

Answer (score 0):

solve with using this function:

```
var counterMarker: Int = 0 


func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        if counterMarker < 2
        {
            counterMarker += 1
            let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
            marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop

            marker.map = mapView


        }
    }
```